# How to access google business API's using REST API in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, google-oauth

I want to use Google API's in my application to fetch some data. I am new to these & I don't have clear Idea on these integrations.

I tried using OAuth but it is doing the signing validation each & everytime to access the API, which takes a lot of implementation time & response time.

In google documentation, it is mentioned to use REST for another alternative, But It is not clear how to implement in PHP (In particularly laravel).

Ref: https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup

Will the Rest API implementation process be easier than OAuth implementation, If yes Please mention the process to implement.